# (CodeIgniter 2) Get mysql function result using active record class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using **CodeIgniter 2 (latest build)**...let's say I have this query:

```
$CI->db->select("FileName, GUID, Count(GUID)");
$query = $CI->db->get('Files');
```

I know I can get GUID & FileName columns using this syntax:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $file_name = $row->FileName;
}
```

But how can I get the `Count(GUID)`?

**PS. This is a simple example to explain my question**. All I need to know is how to get the *composed / mysql function result* using codeigniter active record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's this

```
$CI->db->select("FileName, GUID, Count(GUID) as guidCount");

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $file_name = $row->guidCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->db->select('FileName, GUID, Count(GUID) as guidCount');
    $query = $this->db->get('Files');
    // this will call function once and speed up performance not every time in loop
    $rows = $query->result(); 
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
       echo $row->FileName;
       echo $row->GUID;
       echo $row->guidCount;
    }
```

See more @ https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html